# Tornado Asynchronous simple program

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, tornado

Please I need help with this simple program, I'm not sure if this tornado app is asynchronous (I added async/await), but I believe I should add something.
I want the program to asynchronously listen to requests, thank you in advance.

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import fun, func2

class A(tornado.web.Application):
    async def post(self):
        result = await func2()

class B(tornado.web.Application):
    async def put(self):
        result = await func()

def main():
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/A", A),
        (r"/B", B)
    ])
    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = main()
    app.listen(8000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tornado and asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970919/tornado-and-asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use two applications but one application with two handlers.
The handler methods can be async if you want. Tornado supports this from the ground.

**So probably more like this, [taken from the tornado docs](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html)**:

Typical WebApp Skeleton:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

**Sample for an [async handler method](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html)**:

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

async def asynchronous_fetch(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = await http_client.fetch(url)
    return response.body
```

**So for you example this would more look like this**:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

class AsyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = await http_client.fetch("<some_url")
        return response.body

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/async", AsyncHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

You have to make sure that every module or library you use in the `async` method is
also `async` and does not block the call until it end the request. This is especially true for any I/O you use. Including files, web request, Database access and so on.